# Как правильно передать аргументы в DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно задать `DialogFragment` стиль, для этого я ему присвоил `layout` параметр. Идея такая, я могу вызывать этот `DialogFragment` из разных классов, передавая ему нужный мне `layout`. Так как в зависимости от вызывающего класса `DialogFragment` должен иметь соответствующий вид.

Я делаю это так, вот собственно класс `DialogFragment`

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
    final String LOG_TAG = "MyDialog";
    int layout;


    // Здесь я принимаю входящие аргументы
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        Bundle args = this.getArguments();
        layout = args.getInt("layout");
    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(layout)
                .setCancelable(true);

        return adb.create();
    }

    public void dismissDialog(final MyDialog dialog, int daleyTime) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, daleyTime);
    }

    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onDismiss");
    }

    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onCancel");
    }
}
```

И вот как я передаю аргументы :

```
int daleyTimeFirst = 8 * 1000;
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("key", R.layout.activity_dialog);
dialog .setArguments(args);

dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
dialog.dismissDialog(dialog, daleyTimeFirst);
```

Когда я в классе `MyDialog` явно указываю какой `layout` использовать, то все работает, как только я передаю `layout` как аргумент, то ничего не происходит, в логе печатает только строчку

```
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "MyDialog: onDismiss");
```

Как проверить почему так происходит? Как это починить? Вроде все верно делаю.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Достаете аргумент по ключу `layout` :

```
layout = args.getInt("layout");
```

Записываете аргумент  по ключу `key`:

```
args.putInt("key", R.layout.activity_dialog);
```

Если вы записали `key`, то нужно и доставать `key`, а не `layout`

Comment: ааааа)) точно...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko чтобы так больше не ошибаться делайте так - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/3918680

Comment: Действительно удобно! Но ведь это не исключает возможности создать обьект... Я могу забыть допустим о том, что у меня есть функция которая возвращает мне готовый обьект и начать создавать его руками опять заполняя аргументы...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko просто возьмите в привычку создавать объект через ```newInstance```